# Transform LINQ to normal Foreach

Tags: c#, linq, linqkit

I found below piece of code in one of our project.
I am stuck up for two days :-( trying to understand Aggregate & [LinQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) Expand.

Can you help in transforming below LINQ to normal foreach operation?

```
public Expression<Func<Purchase, bool>> forTarget(List<string> idList)
{
    Expression<Func<Purchase, string>> fc = p => p.ClientId;
    Expression<Func<Purchase, bool>> predicate = m => false;

    return idList.Aggregate(predicate, (p, id) => p.Or(m => fc.Invoke(m) == id), p => p.Expand());
}

internal class Purchase
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Or atleast, any pointer on what this LINQ expression is doing on the list, would be very much helpful.

```
return idList.Aggregate(predicate,
        (p, id) => p.Or(m => fc.Invoke(m) == id),
        p => p.Expand());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function iterates over a collection of items and builds a predicate by adding an `or` condition for each `ClientId` property value.

In the early versions of Linq2SQL there was no support for method `Contains` so you weren't able to perform a query like this:

```
IEnumerable<Purchase> purchases = LoadSelectedItems();
var clientIds = purchases.Select( p => p.ClientId ).ToArray();
var results = db.Clients.Where( c => clientIds.Contains( c.Id )); // Did not work.
```

The workaround for this problem is to create a predicate that would check using `or` whether an `Id` would match a specific value. So, for the above example, if `clientIds = {1, 2, 3}` the `Where` clause would be written as:

```
var results = db.Clients.Where( c => c.Id == 1 || c.Id == 2 || c.Id == 3);
```

As you can see, this kind of statement is not very elegant, becomes unreadable when the collection of values to check against (i. e. `clientIds`) is very large and, most important, you cannot know a priori what the values will be to hardcode them.
So, to overcome this problem, the solution is to generalize the above predicate with a variable collection of values. And this is done simply with the following algorithm:

1. Create an `Expression` that returns `false`; if we return `true` the compiler will short-circuit the evaluation (because we're using `or`) and will return true for all the items;
2. For each item in the collection of values add an `or` clause with the value of the item.

Now, your example can be converted to a foreach this way:

```
// start with a predicate returning false
// this is the seed of the Aggregate method
Expression<Func<Purchase, bool>> predicate = m => false;
// Now, iterate the collection and build the full predicate
foreach( var id in idList)
{
    // Build the predicate by invoking a function which returns the client id of the 
    // purchase and comparing it with the value of the current id from the idList
    predicate = predicate.Or(item => item.ClientId == id);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! it is really helpful. Any pointers on LinQKit Expand() please?

Comment: @Abhijeet, unfortunately, there's not much I can say... `Expand()` method tries to "optimize" the lambda expression so that it can be transformed (efficiently) into a SQL query.